# it is possible to connect landline telephone to PC and retrieve incoming number

Tags: telephony

it is possible to connect landline telephone to PC and retrieve incoming number using javascript, jquery or php and other devices?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how your telephone displays the incoming number? You might find [this earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128204/how-detect-caller-id-from-phone-line) a good start.

Comment: i guess not? thank you for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript? No. jQuery? No. PHP? No. These are all primarily 
web programming languages. This might be able to be done with Java, C, or C++.

Comment: NO?? So i guess i might learn new programming language.. But anyway thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user3044219 Thanks. You are welcome. Would you please click the check next to this answer to accept it? Thank you. It won't hurt. I promise!

Comment: I think you need to give a little more rationale / source of information before such a flat-out "no" answer can be accepted. You can run php on a server connected to a phone, for example. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259185/caller-id-to-php-web-application for an earlier answer that says "yes you can".

Comment: @Floris On a server? Yes. But in the format that the OP was talking about? I don't think so!

Comment: wow. thank you for that reference. that might be very useful. Cheers!

Comment: @TJonS - what is a server other than a computer with some software. The OP obviously already has access to a computer that runs php. I call that a server. But my home computer runs php too. And it has a modem. I think the answer is "it depends". Agree with "javascript - no" and "jQuery - no". Disagree about php.