# Trendnet tfm-561u-Modem Management Disabled

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, tapi, zmodem

As per my  [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984598/how-to-make-caller-id-in-c-net) , I purchased Trendnet TFM-561U device.
I have WIN8 so there was no driver for it on the CD , I googled and found out way to instll WIN7 driver on WIN 8 from this [LINK Here](http://www.getdriver.com/how-to/2410/make-windows-7-drivers-work-windows-8-8-1-inf-modding.html). 
At first it worked fine I got the RING numbers it worked.
After few days I am checkig it classic Phone Tool has orange light. I tried reinstalling the driver , plugged unplugged restarted PC lot of times but its still orange.
On Classic Phone Tool it says

> Modem Management Disabled.

Nowhere I am getting any option to enable. Please help

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is not compatible with WIN8, so had it replaced with

> HiRO H50113 V92 56K External USB

And its working fine.