# How to make outgoing calls in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, twilio, phone-call, tapi, ozeki

I am trying to make outgoing call from C#.net 4.0, with pre-recorded message.I have

> hiro usb modem h50113

already in the system to detect caller id.
I tried googling and found out few links 
1.[OZEKI](http://ozekiphone.com/)
2.[TWILIO](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls)
3. TAPI

in OZEKI I need to get SIP account not sure where to get that, and I am guessing that would cost me.
Twilio seems to be cheap but not sure how to use as there are codes like :

```
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
        string AccountSid = "AC8ca11aff9660bdf011958a5718df9633";
        string AuthToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
        var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

        var options = new CallOptions();
        options.Url = "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml";
        options.To = "+14155551212";
        options.From = "+14158675309";
        var call = twilio.InitiateOutboundCall(options);

        Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
    }
}
```

Not sure where to write this code.
Also I think I can put use to usb-modem to make calls . So please advice what is the best possible way to achieve this and if possible in no cost.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve the issue . As I already had

> hiro usb modem h50113

so i just used AT Command

> ATDT (Phone number)

here is the code :

```
this.sp.WriteLine("ATDT 1234567890" + System.Environment.NewLine);
```

However , only it can ring , theirs no voice . Working on it as soon as I get it will post.

one can refer my old question for better understanding [How to make caller id in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984598/how-to-make-caller-id-in-c-net)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

If you are looking at making outgoing calls with Twilio, I suggest you follow this quick start guide on [making calls in C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/rest). It will take you through the basics.

For a more in depth look, I'd take a look through this tutorial on [building a click to call system with C# ASP.NET MVC](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/click-to-call/csharp/mvc).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi, I et tried using the trial version just to get feel of things, however I am not sure where to write the code, if possible can you please give me. Thanks

Comment: I'm no C# developer I'm afraid, but if you go through that tutorial I linked, it should give you a good idea of what to do.